# Need a simple custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a div that is overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto; and rendering a scrollbar exactly the way I want. I have all of the scrolling functionality and everything I want perfect already. Now, all I want to do is replace the default browser scrollbar with a custom one.

It needs to work in PC IE7+ and Firefox and Mac Safari so it'll need to be JavaScript or jQuery. I've already tried four different plugins that I've found, but none of them worked either because of the version of jQuery (1.6.2), didn't work in all the browsers necessary, or wouldn't work for a horizontal scrollbar, etc. The ones I tried were jQuery UI's slider, jQuery Custom Scrollbar, Tiny Scrollbar and jScrollPane.

I'm hoping there's a simple plugin out there, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: What wasn't working with jScrollPane? I've used jScrollPane with it working in those browsers in the past. I'm curious as to what wasn't working and in which browsers.

Comment: Could you provide an example of something that doesn't work? The plugins you've suggested are all established and functional (i.e. not beta) and ought to do the job :(

Comment: I went for jScrollPage first since it has worked well for me in the past. But unless I'm missing something, it only works for vertical scrollbars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used Flexcroll several times and it works great. Good browser support and it handles touch events for mobile devices as well.

The appearance of the scrollbars is handled with a sprite that's pretty easy to customize. It's 17.5KB which comes out to about 8KB when it's compressed so it's nice not having the overhead of a whole library when this is all you want.

http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. It certainly adds a ton of markup, but it works, and that's all I care about right now.